# I had an error on downloading Autopep8 when typing the command: Cocinstall Autopep8

Tags: python, vim-plugin, coc.nvim

[image]
My vim plug:

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'tell-k/vim-autopep8'
Plug 'plasticboy/vim-markdown'
Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
Plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
Plug 'ap/vim-css-color'
Plug 'preservim/nerdtree'
Plug 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons'
Plug 'weirongxu/coc-explorer'
Plug 'dracula/vim'
Plug 'tsony-tsonev/nerdtree-git-plugin'
Plug 'Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plug 'tiagofumo/vim-nerdtree-syntax-highlight'
Plug 'gruvbox-community/gruvbox'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim'
Plug 'preservim/nerdtree'
Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Plug 'tc50cal/vim-terminal'
Plug 'elvessousa/sobrio'
Plug 'glepnir/dashboard-nvim'
Plug 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'
Plug 'mbbill/undotree'
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'cj/vim-webdevicons'
Plug 'powerline/fonts'
Plug 'VSCodeVim/Vim'
Plug 'github/copilot.vim'
Plug 'mbbill/undotree'
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim' " Fuzzy Finder, Needs Silversearcher-ag for :Ag
Plug 'RRethy/nvim-base16' " Base16 Color Schemes
Plug 'tpope/vim-surround' " Surrounding ysw)
Plug 'tpope/vim-commentary' " For Commenting gcc & gc
Plug 'RRethy/nvim-base16' " Base16 Color Schemes
Plug 'preservim/tagbar', {'on': 'TagbarToggle'} " Tagbar for code navigation
call plug#end()
```

Auto Commands

```
augroup auto_commands
    autocmd BufWrite *.py call CocAction('format')
    autocmd FileType scss setlocal iskeyword+=@-@
augroup end

augroup fish_syntax
    au!
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.fish set syntax=sh
augroup end
```

How can I fix this error, hope you help me

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't run `:CocInstall autopep8`, `CocInstall` is used to install coc.nvim's extensions https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:coc.nvim.

Comment: So now I have to do how you can help me, thanks you